# Elasticity derivations from electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, elasticity

I know that all elastic forces are indeed eletrcomagnetic.

Is there a theory (or a study) which shows in detail the connection between these two branches of physics?

For example: a good starting point would be to derive Hook's law from Maxwell equations

Answer (score 1):

A good exposition of this is given in the first [Feynman lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_12.html). The following image shows the molecular force as a function of distance $r$, where in the quote it is explained how Hooke's law is a *linearization* of this higher order expression related to electromagnetic forces and ultimately quantum mechanics as mentioned by the other answer; obtaining this relation from Maxwell's Equations would not be possible due to the quantum effects and it is probably an empirical law not one found from first principles (cf. [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential))

.

[image]

> If the molecules are pushed only a very small distance closer, or pulled only a very small distance farther than d, the corresponding distance along the curve of Fig. 12–2 is also very small, and can then be approximated by a straight line. Therefore, in many circumstances, if the displacement is not too great the force is proportional to the displacement. This principle is known as Hooke’s law, or the law of elasticity, which says that the force in a body which tries to restore the body to its original condition when it is distorted is proportional to the distortion. This law, of course, holds true only if the distortion is relatively small; when it gets too large the body will be torn apart or crushed, depending on the kind of distortion. The amount of force for which Hooke’s law is valid depends upon the material; for instance, for dough or putty the force is very small, but for steel it is relatively large. Hooke’s law can be nicely demonstrated with a long coil spring, made of steel and suspended vertically. A suitable weight hung on the lower end of the spring produces a tiny twist throughout the length of the wire, which results in a small vertical deflection in each turn and adds up to a large displacement if there are many turns. If the total elongation produced, say, by a 100-gram weight, is measured, it is found that additional weights of 100 grams will each produce an additional elongation that is very nearly equal to the stretch that was measured for the first 100 grams. This constant ratio of force to displacement begins to change when the spring is overloaded, i.e., Hooke’s law no longer holds.

So if a spring (made of molecules) is stretched too far the molecules will break their inter-molecular bonds that depend on things like quantum spin.

Answer (score 0):

The forces holding things together come from chemical bonding which, except for ionic bonding,  is not just Maxwell. Metals for example are held together by covalent bonds, which are inherently quantum mechanical.